# Structuring A Database with Multiple Foreign Keys For High Performance

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, database-design

I am trying to build a local database for android. I am a little lost.

The app is a document management app.. I need to save the following...

```
Document
--------
Id
import date
List<DocTags>
extension 
etc
```

then I have a number of docTags that have different information

```
Location
-------
id
name
lat
long

Company
------
Id
name
Street
town
```

around 10 other doc types.

I realise I need a table to store all the docTag ids that are assigned to a document but these relate to lots of different tables. My problem is that I need to retrieve a list of documents by searching for the doctag Id or multiple doctag ids. We need to assume we have 10,000 documents of more which could equate to 40,000 doc tags. So performance is a major issue. What is the best way to structure the database?

I will also need to search the doctag names.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to a text retrieval engine?  You can store the doc tags as text and just search them as if thegcwere keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have a many to many JOIN table relating Document to Tag.

I would *not* have those tags in multiple tables.  That breaks first normal form.  If other tables need to refer to Tag rows, give them JOIN tables as well.

Your comments below suggest that either a normalization refresher is necessary or that a relational model might not be the best choice for your problem.  Perhaps a NoSQL, document based solution would fit better.

Comment: I was referring to 40,000 doc tags in the database. 10,000 docs thats only 4 tags each. Granted 40,000 unique ones but these are the estimates the server team have given me

Comment: The rest of my answer stands.  I'll delete that bit.

Comment: I missed a bit off. To initially get the doctag id to search for the document I will need to search doctags by name. Is there away to incorporate that as well?

Comment: Do a JOIN.  It sounds like you want to do a query for tags and then a query for each tag over documents.  That's dying a latent, (n+1) query death.  Learn how to write a JOIN query and bring them all back in one go.

Comment: Yeah I know how to do a join. But surely I would need to do a number of join queries and union them as there will be 10 or so doctag tables. With potentially 40,000 entries I would have thought that performance would suffer

Comment: Whatever, dude.  Ten doctag tables?  Not one?  That's not first normal form.  Your schema probably will be slow, but it'll be because you designed it poorly or the relational model isn't a good choice.  Learn how to normalize and see if NoSQL might be a better fit.

Comment: hey man, I am not trying to be difficult I am just trying to solve the problem. This question is about designing the db so I get it right. I know how to normalise but I have 10 doc types that have different fields so I can't use one table. Is that not a legitimate question?

 I will look into noSQL but its doesn't seem to be supported. Maybe I can find a 3rd party library

Comment: @jiduvah - why would you want 10 doctag tables? A single doctag table with a "type" column and a number of columns to store the doctag data should suffice - refer to the design of Data in ContactsContract. Also, values in SQLite are dynamically typed anyways (tl;dr: do as *duffymo* says)

Comment: Jens has your jam.  Ten tables should be a warning sign (two should have been enough).  See why?  You shouldn't have  to add a new table every time there's a new tag type.  Better to add rows in an existing table.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. I guess I was thinking that lots of null fields wouldn't be a good thing but as I don't need to search them its not a problem (yet). In your answer you wrote "I would have have those tags in multiple tables" did you mean the opposite?

Answer (score -2):

I'm only ever used SQLite once or twice, but based on my experience with other 
database systems, I would strongly recommend starting with a solid relational schema, 
and assessing the performance, before trying anything else.

In your case, I think the schema would look like this.

[image: Sample DB schema with two doctags]

(Of course with two additional tables for each doctag).

You will have a lot of tables, and probably quite a long query to get all the information, 
but this is not necessarily a bad thing. Having the schema relational will allow the query 
optimizer to do its job, and will make future queries much easier to write.

A query to get the document, and any information on it's location and company (or return 
null if the document does not have this tag) would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Document
    LEFT JOIN DocumentLocation ON Document.ID=DocumentLocation.DocumentID
        INNER JOIN Location ON DocumentLocation.LocationID=Location.LocationID
    LEFT JOIN DocumentCompany ON Document.ID=DocumentCompany.DocumentID
        INNER JOIN Company ON DocumentCompany.CompanyID=Company.CompanyID
```

If the performance of this does turn out to be too slow, you can then investigate strategies for improving the performance (e.g. caching, additional indexes) depending on the expected usage pattern of your application.

Comment: sorry Daniel, its not the right answer thanks for the effort you put in tho